# How to create more columns easier?

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm new to iOS Prgramming and I am trying to create an app that will list the activities for the day, although I would like to easily create more columns with 2 images and some text as shown in the picture:

[image]

How would I do that? I've created a class where I can generate both the images and the text for each element, but I don't know how to make it so it's automatically placed in 2 UIImages and a label just below the other columns.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest going with UITableView with a UITableViewCell which contains: 2 UIImages and 1 Label.

Try finding a simple tutorial for UITableView, for example, [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview) or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html).

Then you may have other question while implementing but those are more certain. Currently, your question is very broad so I hope my answer helps you to get started.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I have a question now, I've configured my Custom Cell and it loads up although my samples does not show up (no code in TableViewController class is being run) how can that be?

Comment: I think you didn't assign delegate and datasource probably. do this: `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: I found out how to fix it and did a code cleanup :)